# Ajax pagination doesn't change the active link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

Hello I am going to make an ajax pagination using codeigniter..
I've tried the code but it seems pagination doesn't change the active link..
please help me..
 here is my ajax

```
    $(function() {
applyPagination();
function applyPagination() {
  $("#paging a").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "ajax=1",
      url: url,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#things").html("");
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        $("#things").html(msg);
        applyPagination();
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
}
```

});

another ajax code I've tried

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#paging a").click(function()
    {
        var this_url = $(this).attr("href");

        $.post(this_url,{ },function(data){
            $("div#things").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

my view pagination id

```
<div class="paging" id="paging">
<aside>
<?php echo $links; ?>
</aside>
</div>
```

My controller

```
public function index($start_row="")
{
    /*Pagination*/
    $start_row = $this->uri->segment(4);

    $per_page=5;
    if(trim($start_row) == '')
    {
        $start_row = 0;
    }

    $result = $this->abouthistory_model->history_list();
    $data["CatId"]=$this->viewbook_model->getCategory();
    $total_rows=count($result);
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."about/abouthistory/index";
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
    $config['per_page'] =$per_page; 
    $config['is_ajax_paging']  =  TRUE; // default FALSE
    $config['paging_function'] = 'ajax_paging'; // Your jQuery paging

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $resultLimited =  $this->abouthistory_model->history_listLimited($start_row,$per_page);
    $data["CatId"]=$this->viewbook_model->getCategory();
    $data["links"]=$this->pagination->create_links();
```

please help me

Comment: Try it without ajax, it might be you're using the wrong segment, And while we're at it, You don't have to re-attach a click event every-time you get a result into a div (As long as you're not reloading your click event would still be there).

Comment: but I need the ajax because I will implement it in other pages that contain 2 paging..:(

Comment: Where is load->view()?

Comment: I am not telling you to lose the ajax part permanently, I am telling you that you're specifying the wrong  uri segment, it should be 3 not 4 that's why it's giving you the wrong result.

Comment: mmm..the uri segment need 4 because of http://xxx/xxx/about/abouthistory the segment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a perfect ajax pagination for codeigniter, please refer the below link:

http://tohin.wordpress.com/2008/08/12/codeigniter-ajax-pagination/

me using this, working fine....

here is the code that i used to display employee details:

--ajax controller--

```
public function employeeListAjax()
{
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        redirect(site_url(), 'refresh');
    }
    $config['anchor_class'] = '';
    $config['show_count'] = true;
    $config['div'] = '#emp_list'; // div for displaying ajax
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('employee/employeeListAjax');
    $config['total_rows'] = sizeof($this->emp->empdetail());
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $this->jquery_pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['links'] = $this->jquery_pagination->create_links();
    $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['empdet'] = $this->emp->empdetail($config['per_page'], $data['page']);
    $this->load->view('modules/employee/ajax_emp_list', $data);
}
```

--ajax script in page--

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $.post("<?php echo site_url('employee/employeeListAjax');?>",
        {
        },
        function(response)
        {
        setTimeout("showAjax('#emp_list', '"+escape(response)+"')", 100);
        });
    });
</script>
```

u have to download the jquery_pagination library from:

https://github.com/neotohin/CodeIgniter-Ajax-pagination-Library/blob/master/Jquery_pagination.php

and copy it to library folder in application folder in codeigniter.

before using u need to load the library using:

```
$this->load->library('Jquery_Pagination');
```

Thank you...

**showAjax** is a custom js function which used to display the desponse with some effect:

```
<script>
    function showAjax(id, response)
    {
    jQuery(id).hide();
    jQuery(id).html(unescape(response));
    jQuery(id).fadeIn(200);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you try the jquery one or the ajax one by gingin? :)

Comment: I want to ask you..I dont understand this part $html =  $this->jquery_pagination->create_links() . br(1)
    .  $this->table->generate($this->model

Comment: It's because I'm  not using table..how to generate if Im not using table?

Comment: and then what are you doing with the view? echo something? Or please share your code for that pagination issues..thanks :)

Comment: thanks..renish I need some help..I have error that showAjax is not defined..why?

Comment: also what is this code means if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        redirect(site_url(), 'refresh');
    }

Comment: if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) is used for : that particular controller can be accessed only by ajax methods thatis from a script: we cannot access that controller by directly entering its url.